# jQuery XML export or Simple JavaScript file download

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, file, download

I have dynamically created a xml string form a JSON object returned from server. I need to give the user to download this as a file so that when the user click the button named export he/she receives a downloadable.xml file and can be save d on local machine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you generated the file on the server or on the client?

If you have generated the file at the server you can use the [content-disposition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519) header. You also need to set the content type to application/xml or text/xml.

If you have generated the file using jQuery, then it isn't possible for the user to save it locally. Javascript isn't allowed access to the file system.

Comment: Yes, i have generated the xml string on the client using jQuery, and i want when the user clicks a button, he will be prompted to save the xml as a file and user chooses the location.

Comment: As I've said this is not possible with javascript. You need to consider an alternative solution. Like when user clicks a button the xml is Ajax posted to a server location, the server gets the xml and returns it as an attachment.

Answer (score 3):

I was recently looking for something similar, and came across [Downloadify](http://downloadify.info/).  It appears to use a feature of Flash 10 to work around the filesystem limitation of JavaScript.